# Java: Giving more weight to higher values among inputs

Tags: java, algorithm, compare

I have some inputs say x1,x2,x3. I have to multiply each input with some weight and add them. Like alpha * x1 + beta * x2 + gamma * x3.
Range of x1,x2,x3 is 0 to 1.
Range of weights is also 0 to 1. 
I want some algorithm to give more weight to higher values and less weight to lower values.

Like if x1 has higher value among three then 60% weight age can be given to x1.
x2 has 2nd highest value 30% to it and 20% to last value completing 100%. 
What I have tried so far is given below but values are static, I am giving weight 0.6 to highest value the 0.3 and 0.2 respectively. Is there any way to give weight dynamically according to value of input?

```
if (x1>x2 and x1>x3 ) {
    if (x2>x3) {
        sum= 0.6*x1 + 0.3*x2 + 0.2*x3;
    }

    if (x3>x2) {
        sum= 0.6*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.3*x3;
    }
}

if (x2>x3 and x2>x1 ) {
    if (x1>x3) {
        sum= 0.3*x1 + 0.6*x2 + 0.2*x3;
    }

    if (x3>x1) {
        sum= 0.2*x1 + 0.6*x2 + 0.3*x3;
    }
}

if (x3>x2 and x3>x1 ) {
    if (x2>x1) {
        sum= 0.2*x1 + 0.3*x2 + 0.6*x3;
    }

    if (x1>x2) {
        sum= 0.3*x1 + 0.2*x2 + 0.6*x3;
    }
}
```

Comment: So 60 + 30 + 20 = 100? Have you tried anything? What's the concrete problem you're facing?

Comment: Yes.At the moment I am simply using If Else giving static weight-age like if x1>x2 and x3 then 0.6 * x1. I want some algorithm to cal. it for me automatically based on higher value.

Comment: Also if value of some input is much higher it will get more weight-age and if inputs have less difference then lower weight-age. Two input can be same then equal weight-age to these inputs.

Comment: OK, so edit your question to tell what you actually want to do, including how, precisely, the weights should be computed, and show what you have tried. It looks to me that you simply want to sum the squares of each number.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying *but values are static*. 
If by that you mean that you hardcoded values like:

```
double x1 = 1.0;
double x2 = 2.0;
double x3 = 3.0;
```

then the solution is to get them by user input:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("x1=");
double x1 = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.print("x2=");
double x2 = scanner.nextDouble();
System.out.print("x3=");
double x3 = scanner.nextDouble();

scanner.close();
```

Then you make all the calculations.